# android:digits Problem

Tags: android

I am using the following xml to limit input to digits only in an EditText widget. The android:digits attribute uses the below array resource. Everything works great except for the fact that I can't enter the number 4 even though its in the array. Any Ideas?

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/mynumber"  
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="40dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:textColor="#aaffaa"
    android:numeric="integer"
    android:digits="@array/digits"
    android:background="#00000000"
    android:inputType="phone"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:singleLine="true" />
```

String array resource excerpt:

```
<string-array name="digits">
  <item>0</item>
  <item>1</item>
  <item>2</item>
  <item>3</item>
  <item>4</item>
  <item>5</item>
  <item>6</item>
  <item>7</item>
  <item>8</item>
  <item>9</item>
</string-array>
```

Comment: is it working if you dont' define the string-array but just use android:digits="0123456789"?

Comment: Agreed. Get rid of the string array and use `android:digits="0123456789"`

Comment: Yes it does. It would appear this a bug in how the array is parsed?

Comment: Maybe, if your are sure that you really can't enter 4. I can't see a failure in this piece of code by now. But neverthelss, just use android:digits="0123456789" and don't care about ;)

Answer (score 3):

`android:digits` must be a string **value** see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:digits. When using`string-array` it will compile, but not work as expected, causing random numbers to be missed from the input.